# Java join List<List<Object>> with Collections

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-stream

I have a two classes Formulary and Pieces. Formulary has to keep a list of Pieces, because it is a formulary of pieces and I need to keep track of which Pieces Objects are in a Formulary:

```
class Piece {
    String id;
    String name;
    String info;
}

class Formulary{
    String id;
    TreeMap<String, Piece> pieces;
    
    public Collection<Piece> getPieces() {return pecas.values();}
}
```

Formulary has a method getPieces() to return the list of pieces it has contained.

It happens that I need to join pieces that are in multiple formularies. This is what i did so far:

```
 TreeMap<String, Formulary> forms;    
 List<Collection<Pieces>> piecesFromForms = forms.values().stream().map(Formulary::getPieces).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The problem is that I was only capable to return a `list<Collection<Pieces>>`, but need to join all the list of pieces in the forms and return a `List<Pieces>` and I couldn't find a way to do this with collections.

I could do with for loops. I know, but I'm trying to get better with collections, as they work much faster.

Comment: I think `flatMap` is what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you for the tip Jeroen, but I just started to use Collections, I used to make hundreds of For loops in my code, I'm refractoring everything. The simple ones I can do for sure, but when It starts to become hacky I don't know very much about colletions yet. If you could give an example I'd appreciate

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Stream.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)), which expects a *function* which turns a new stream out of each stream element.

```
List<Piece> piecesFromForms = forms.values().stream()
    .flatMap(formulary -> formulary.getPieces().stream())
    .toList(); // for Java 16 or collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Or Java 16 [`Stream.mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)), which might perform better if collection of `Piece` objects contained within each `Formulary` is tiny (*literally a couple of elements or might be empty at all*).

```
List<Piece> piecesFromForms = forms.values().stream()
    .<Piece>mapMulti((formulary, consumer) -> formulary.getPieces().forEach(consumer))
    .toList();
```

Comment: thanks for your edit on my answer mate. And for the +1. Java fellas!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
List<Collection<Pieces>> piecesFromForms = forms.values()
    .stream()
    .Map(Formulary::getPieces)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Sorry for the "Romaneio" inside the code, I abstracted the classes and changed the names for better undestanding, But I'm happy you got the ideia.

Comment: It didn't work, I think it must be the Java version. But yet I considered the anshwer, thank you.

Comment: you should use `Collection::stream` instead of `List::stream`

Comment: I changed it to `Collection::stream`